# Errors when using stemDocument in R

Tags: r, text

When I try to run

```
    paper <- tm_map(paper, stemDocument)
```

I got the following error message.

```
    Error in SnowballC::wordStem(x, as.character(language)) : 
      language `lat' is not available for stemming
```

Before I ran stemDocument, I applied the following treatment to the paper I was working on.

```
    toSpace<-content_transformer(function(x,pattern)gsub(pattern,replacement="  ", x))
    paper <- tm_map(paper, toSpace, "/")
    paper <-tm_map(paper, toSpace, "&")
    paper <- tm_map(paper, toSpace, "@")
    paper <- tm_map(paper, toSpace, "\\|")
    paper<- tm_map(paper, content_transformer(tolower))
    paper<-tm_map(paper, removeNumbers)
    paper<-tm_map(paper, removePunctuation)
    paper<-tm_map(paper, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
    paper<-tm_map(paper, removeWords,c("foul","loudly"))
    paper<-tm_map(paper, stripWhitespace)


    toStrings<- content_transformer(function(x, from, to) gsub(from, to, x))#works  
    paper<-tm_map(paper,toStrings, "lady walmsley told yesterday", "said")#working
    paper<-tm_map(paper,toStrings," proved royally passage","NEXT")#working
```

The session information

> sessionInfo() 
>           R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
>           Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

```
    locale:
    [1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936 
    [2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936   
    [3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936
    [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                                                   
    [5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936    

    attached base packages:
    [1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
    [7] methods   base     

    other attached packages:
     [1] wordcloud_2.5          bnlearn_3.7.1         
     [3] Rgraphviz_2.10.0       graph_1.44.1          
     [5] scales_0.2.4           dplyr_0.4.1           
     [7] qdap_2.2.0             RColorBrewer_1.1-2    
     [9] qdapTools_1.1.0        qdapRegex_0.2.0       
    [11] qdapDictionaries_1.0.2 ggplot2_1.0.0         
    [13] SnowballC_0.5.1        tm_0.6                
    [15] NLP_0.1-6             

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
     [1] assertthat_0.1      BiocGenerics_0.12.1 bitops_1.0-6       
     [4] chron_2.3-45        colorspace_1.2-4    data.table_1.9.4   
     [7] DBI_0.3.1           devtools_1.7.0      digest_0.6.8       
    [10] gdata_2.13.3        gender_0.4.3        gridExtra_0.9.1    
    [13] gtable_0.1.2        gtools_3.4.1        httr_0.6.1         
    [16] igraph_0.7.1        jsonlite_0.9.14     magrittr_1.5       
    [19] MASS_7.3-35         munsell_0.4.2       openNLP_0.2-3      
    [22] openNLPdata_1.5.3-1 parallel_3.1.2      plotrix_3.5-11     
    [25] plyr_1.8.1          proto_0.3-10        Rcpp_0.11.4        
    [28] RCurl_1.95-4.5      reports_0.1.4       reshape2_1.4.1     
    [31] rJava_0.9-6         slam_0.1-32         stats4_3.1.2       
    [34] stringr_0.6.2       tools_3.1.2         venneuler_1.1-0    
    [37] xlsx_0.5.7          xlsxjars_0.6.1      XML_3.98-1.1
```

Can anyone explain to me why this happened and how to make stemDocument work?
Really appreciate your help~!

The document "paper" under analysis is a plain .txt file, the Hamlet.
I thought wrongly it is an english file.
So how can I change this lat file into an english file so that I can stem it?

I just ran meta(paper,"language")

```
    > meta(paper, "language")
    [[1]]
    [1] "lat"

    [[2]]
    [1] "lat"
```

-----------------------------part of the-content of the paper.txt--------------------------

```
HAMLET
DRAMATIS PERSONAE
```

CLAUDIUS    king of Denmark. (KING CLAUDIUS:)
HAMLET  son to the late, and nephew to the present king.
POLONIUS    lord chamberlain. (LORD POLONIUS:)
HORATIO friend to Hamlet.
LAERTES son to Polonius.
LUCIANUS    nephew to the king.

......

OPHELIA daughter to Polonius.
    Lords, Ladies, Officers, Soldiers, Sailors, Messengers,
    and other Attendants. (Lord:)
    (First Sailor:)
    (Messenger:)
    Ghost of Hamlet's Father. (Ghost:)
SCENE   Denmark.

```
HAMLET
```

ACT I
SCENE I Elsinore. A platform before the castle.
    [FRANCISCO at his post. Enter to him BERNARDO]
BERNARDO    Who's there?
FRANCISCO   Nay, answer me: stand, and unfold yourself.
BERNARDO    Long live the king!
FRANCISCO   Bernardo?
BERNARDO    He.
FRANCISCO   You come most carefully upon your hour.
BERNARDO    'Tis now struck twelve; get thee to bed, Francisco.
FRANCISCO   For this relief much thanks: 'tis bitter cold,
    And I am sick at heart.
BERNARDO    Have you had quiet guard?
FRANCISCO   Not a mouse stirring.
BERNARDO    Well, good night.
    If you do meet Horatio and Marcellus,
    The rivals of my watch, bid them make haste.

Comment: What does `meta(paper, "language")` return? What language are the documents in? It appears to be "lat" and not "english." The stemmer only knows how to deal with languages in the list from `SnowballC:::getStemLanguages()`. I suppose you could use the more generic "porter" stemmer but I think that's still primarily intended for use with english words.

Comment: Adding to @MrFlick, how did stopwords work if the text is not English?  Second, qdap's stemmer is just a wrapper for tm's stemmer.  Third, have you tried any sort of iconv() functions on the text?

Comment: @MrFlick How can R tell if a document is lat or english?

Comment: @lawyeR No, I didn't run iconv(paper). Would this matter? I dont' know how to stem this document at this point.

Comment: I believe that the function might convert your latin coding to English.  Why don't you look at the help for it and experiment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i'm not sure how you created/imported the `paper` object, but something set it's language attribute to "lat." You can override the default language selection by explicitly choosing english. For example

```
paper <- tm_map(paper, stemDocument, language="english")
```

Comment: Thank you very much @MrFlick!!! Adding language="english" indeed works~! The Hamlet file was obtained from a class website and I directly downloaded from there. I didn't realize I can override the default language.